# Increasing the metric of default route in CentOS with DHCP

Tags: linux, centos, route

I am setting up a server (VM to be precise) that runs CentOS 6.4. I have an `eth0` adapter on the CentOS machine that has connection to the Internet (through a bridged network on the host). The eth0 adapter is configured through DHCP. So far, so good.

I also want to have a VPN client running on the server and **to have it connect through the `tun0` adapter to the Internet**. The VPN client connects successfully using OpenVPN. It produces a `default` route with metric 0.

So, first of all, this is possible, right? Second, as far as I understand, there are 2 ways to go about this: increase the metric of the `route` that runs through `eth0` or decrease the metric of the `route` that runs through `tun0`.

I have attempted to do both, but have been unsuccessful so far. I have tried these: adding a `METRIC=100` line in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, however it does not change the metric of the route.

I have also tried adding a `metric` option to the `client.conf` file for OpenVPN. This also had no effect (I believe this to be due to there being a `pull` option in this file).

My most radical idea was to manually delete the `route` for `eth0` and replace it with the same route, but with higher metric. Unfortunately, I can not do that either, as restarting the network will reset the settings and having a daemon running that does it all the time doesn't seem a good solution.

I am open to suggestions and ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that is resulting in you trying to mess around with your metric?  **Adjusting your metric, is almost certainly the wrong solution**.  If you are trying to redirect all your traffic over the VPN using the `redirect-gateway` option, then let me suggest you try `redirect-gateway def1` instead.  This options sets up a two routes (`0/1`, `128/1`) instead of changing the default gateway.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Zoredache My problem is that I'd like to connect to the Internet through the OpenVPN `tun0` adapter, and instead I have about 50% chance to do so, since both `eth0` and `tun0` provide Internet connection. You may be correct about metrics being the wrong solution. Could you elaborate further about `redirect-gateway`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand the problem correctly then you basically have a computer with an interface set to DHCP, and you want to connect to a VPN and pass all your traffic through the VPN.

You are having problems when the DHCP server renews the lease it is re-adding the gateway provided by the DHCP server.

I suggest you update your `client.conf` and replace the `redirect-gateway` option with the `redirect-gateway def1`.  This instructs OpenVPN to add two routes that are more specific than the default gateway instead of removing the pre-existing default gateway and adding a new one.

When you use `redirect-gateway def1` you get a route table that looks somewhat like below.  Since the most specific matching route is the one that is used, the routes for `0.0.0.0/1`, and `128.0.0.0/1` take precednce over the default route, but without the messy business of having to remove/replace the default route.  It also removes the requirement that you make sure no other software change the default route.

```
# ip route
10.3.195.17 dev tun_rem  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.3.195.18 
172.26.222.0/23 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.26.222.204 
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.3.195.17 dev tun_rem 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.3.195.17 dev tun_rem
default via 172.26.222.1 dev eth1
```

If the `redirect-gateway` setting is not being set in your `client.conf`, then you may need to also add the `"route-nopull` option to ignore the routes being pulled from the VPN server.

Comment: Thanks for not only solving the problem at hand, but pointing out my original idea for a solution was wrong. The help is very much appreciated.